# Can you enable Google Analytics after consent is given in AngularFire?

Tags: angular, firebase, cookies, google-analytics, angularfire

I want to create a GDPR complying website using Google Analytics. For that, I would like to ask the user for consent before actually saving any cookies.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on that topic, as AngularFire has [next to no documentation (and even less for the new API)](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md) and Firebase provides only [documentation for IOS/Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios).

**What I have tried:**

1. Providing a config using the providers array in `app.module.ts`
2. Try setting `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(analytics, false);` in `provideAnalytics`
3. Try setting `window['ga-disable-analyticsId'] = true;` in `main.ts`

All these methods still save cookies to my browser on load.

Are there any official or unofficial methods to get AngularFire to do what I want?

| Name | AngularFire | Firebase | Angular |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Version | 7.2.0 | 9.6.1 | 13.1.0 |

Comment: May sound silly but did you replace analyticsId by your actual analytics id ? The property on the Windows object must be set before GA initializes, not familiar with angularFire but I believe it should then ne sera on window before AngularFire starts up.

Comment: @lkostka Do you mean that in the `window['ga-disable-analyticsId']` I have to actually write `window['ga-disable-G-ABCD......']`? `main.ts` should 100% run before anything else, so it should run before AngularFire though, so that is not the problem.

Comment: yes as per those docs here, you should write the id https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out

Comment: @lkostka Can you form that as an answer? I can't check right now if this is what fixes it, but it might help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mat not be the solution here, but according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out) data collection is disabled at the stream id  (GA4) or property id (UA) level, so inside window['ga-disable-analyticsId], analyticsId should instead be the actual id.

Comment: This was totally the solution, but I already solved it without AngularFire. After implementing AngularFire again, the `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(analytics, false);` solution worked as well.